# How to map/join some index column of a multiindex pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, join, mapping

Lets say I have a DataFrame `df` with a multi index ['siec', 'geo'] (shown in *italic*):

| *siec* | *geo* | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *a* | *DE* | 1 |
| *a* | *FR* | 2 |

and a mapping DataFrame `mapping_df` from `geo` to `id_region` with a single index ['geo']:

| *geo* | id_region |
| --- | --- |
| *DE* | 10 |
| *FR* | 20 |

=> How can I join/merge/replace the index column 'geo' of `df` with the values of the column 'id_region' from `mapping_df`?

**Expected result** with new multi index ['siec', 'id_region']:

| *siec* | *id_region* | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *a* | *10* | 1 |
| *a* | *20* | 2 |

I tried following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'siec': 'a', 'geo': 'DE', 'value': 1}, {'siec': 'a', 'geo': 'FR', 'value': 1}])
df.set_index(['siec', 'geo'], inplace=True)

mapping_df = pd.DataFrame([{'geo': 'DE', 'id_region': 10}, {'geo': 'FR', 'id_region': 20}])
mapping_df.set_index(['geo'], inplace=True)

joined_data = df.join(mapping_df)

merged_data = df.merge(mapping_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

but it does not do what I want. It adds an additional column and keeps the old index.

| *siec* | *geo* | value | id_region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *a* | *DE* | 1 | 10 |
| *a* | *FR* | 2 | 20 |

=> Is there a convenient method for my use case or would I need to manually correct the index after a joining step?

As a workaround, I could `reindex()` the DataFrames, do some joining manipulations and then reintroduce some multi index.

However, **I would like to avoid switching back and forth** between the indexed and non-indexed versions of the DataFrames if possible (?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows.

- Use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) to select only level `1` (or: `geo`) and apply [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with `mapping_df['id_region']` as mapper.
- Wrap the result inside [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) to overwrite level `1`.
- Finally, chain [`Index.set_names`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.set_names.html) to rename the level (or use [`MultiIndex.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.rename.html)).

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(
    df.index.get_level_values(1).map(mapping_df['id_region']), level=1)\
    .set_names('id_region', level=1)

print(df)

                value
siec id_region       
a    10             1
     20             2
```